# How do I calculate my provisional tax so I don't get so much tax back?

Tags: taxes, south-africa

I am a South African provisional taxpayer with my own business. I usually calculate my provisional taxes only based on my business incomes and expenses. Then when I file my income tax I have a ton of deductions like medical aid and retirement and donations. I get a ton of tax back so SARS always selects me for verification (which I don't mind because I just send my paperwork).

I know there's place in my provisional to allocate deductions but I don't know how to calculate what to put there because my certificates don't arrive until much later and I don't want get penalized for underpaying. How do I calculate what to put there so it's more accurate, or is it better to leave it and over pay on provisional?